# Duplicity does not start new chains with full-if-older-than

Tags: backup, duplicity

I want to use duplicity to backup most of my home folder to Backblaze. I'm trying to set it up so that it does a full backup every month. For this I'm using the following commands which are run daily:

```
LOCAL_DIR="/home/username"
EXCLUDE="\
 --exclude /home/username/temp \
 --exclude /home/username/.cache \
"
duplicity \
 backup --full-if-older-than 1M ${EXCLUDE} --progress \
 ${LOCAL_DIR} b2://${B2_ID}:${B2_KEY}@${B2_BUCKET}
```

This successfully creates a backup every day, however duplicity never creates a new chain - there was one full backup in September and since then only incrementals. I want to start a new chain with a full backup each month.

Some things I've tried with no luck:

- change 1M to 30D
- change order of the options (e.g. excludes first)
- change `backup` to `incremental`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Here's an example output of the command:

```
+ duplicity backup --full-if-older-than 1M --exclude /home/username/temp --exclude /home/username/.cache --progress /home/username b2://B2_ID:B2_KEY@B2_BUCKET
Local and Remote metadata are synchronized, no sync needed.
Last full backup date: Thu Sep 21 16:19:13 2023
3.9MB 00:01:12 [291.5KB/s] [========================================>] 100% ETA 0sec
--------------[ Backup Statistics ]--------------
StartTime 1702050982.47 (Fri Dec  8 16:56:22 2023)
EndTime 1702051043.61 (Fri Dec  8 16:57:23 2023)
ElapsedTime 61.15 (1 minute 1.15 seconds)
SourceFiles 540202
SourceFileSize 77232368533 (71.9 GB)
NewFiles 39
NewFileSize 15434498 (14.7 MB)
DeletedFiles 11
ChangedFiles 78
ChangedFileSize 70757910 (67.5 MB)
ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
DeltaEntries 128
RawDeltaSize 19617995 (18.7 MB)
TotalDestinationSizeChange 3410741 (3.25 MB)
Errors 0
-------------------------------------------------
```

And here's the collection status:

```
+ duplicity collection-status --progress b2://B2_ID:B2_KEY@B2_BUCKET
Last full backup date: Thu Sep 21 16:19:13 2023
Collection Status
-----------------
Connecting with backend: BackendWrapper
Archive dir: /home/username/.cache/duplicity/a52568672c187fdf7e6d79e12a4df37f

Found 0 secondary backup chain(s).

Found primary backup chain with matching signature chain:
-------------------------
Chain start time: Thu Sep 21 16:19:13 2023
Chain end time: Fri Dec  8 16:55:20 2023
Number of contained backup sets: 72
Total number of contained volumes: 331
 Type of backup set:                            Time:      Num volumes:
                Full         Thu Sep 21 16:19:13 2023               222
         Incremental         Fri Sep 22 13:41:57 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Sep 22 14:04:53 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Sep 22 14:07:21 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sat Sep 23 23:07:51 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sun Sep 24 14:38:12 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sun Sep 24 15:44:06 2023                 1
         Incremental         Mon Sep 25 14:49:06 2023                 1
         Incremental         Tue Sep 26 10:31:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Wed Sep 27 14:24:04 2023                 1
         Incremental         Thu Sep 28 11:10:04 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Sep 29 14:29:04 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sat Sep 30 12:08:39 2023                 2
         Incremental         Sun Oct  1 11:33:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Mon Oct  2 10:22:05 2023                 2
         Incremental         Tue Oct  3 15:37:05 2023                 6
         Incremental         Wed Oct  4 13:50:36 2023                 1
         Incremental         Thu Oct  5 14:28:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Oct  6 13:39:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sat Oct  7 14:42:07 2023                 2
         Incremental         Sun Oct  8 08:21:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Mon Oct  9 19:11:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Tue Oct 10 10:06:05 2023                 2
         Incremental         Wed Oct 11 11:07:05 2023                 2
         Incremental         Thu Oct 12 11:21:05 2023                 2
         Incremental         Fri Oct 13 21:04:58 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sat Oct 14 13:27:15 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sun Oct 15 12:13:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Mon Oct 16 11:27:06 2023                 1
         Incremental         Tue Oct 17 12:10:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Thu Oct 19 14:37:53 2023                 2
         Incremental         Fri Oct 20 19:13:03 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sat Oct 21 14:26:06 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sun Oct 22 11:49:55 2023                 3
         Incremental         Mon Oct 23 12:20:05 2023                 8
         Incremental         Wed Oct 25 17:05:08 2023                 1
         Incremental         Wed Oct 25 18:28:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Thu Oct 26 21:35:52 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Oct 27 14:36:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sat Oct 28 09:06:04 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sun Oct 29 20:04:52 2023                 1
         Incremental         Mon Oct 30 13:30:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Tue Oct 31 11:24:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Wed Nov  1 18:36:05 2023                 2
         Incremental         Fri Nov  3 09:49:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sat Nov  4 03:27:05 2023                 2
         Incremental         Sun Nov  5 19:50:06 2023                 2
         Incremental         Mon Nov  6 17:49:17 2023                 1
         Incremental         Tue Nov  7 12:38:34 2023                 1
         Incremental         Tue Nov  7 19:10:04 2023                 1
         Incremental         Wed Nov  8 18:12:09 2023                 1
         Incremental         Thu Nov  9 13:43:17 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Nov 10 20:29:17 2023                 2
         Incremental         Sat Nov 11 14:19:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sun Nov 12 21:27:09 2023                 3
         Incremental         Mon Nov 13 14:29:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Tue Nov 14 18:05:55 2023                 3
         Incremental         Wed Nov 15 10:06:05 2023                 3
         Incremental         Thu Nov 16 14:45:06 2023                 5
         Incremental         Fri Nov 17 10:40:05 2023                 4
         Incremental         Sun Nov 19 18:14:08 2023                 1
         Incremental         Mon Nov 20 16:51:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Wed Nov 22 14:23:07 2023                 1
         Incremental         Thu Nov 23 16:27:06 2023                 1
         Incremental         Sun Dec  3 17:10:06 2023                 1
         Incremental         Mon Dec  4 21:17:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Tue Dec  5 13:51:06 2023                 1
         Incremental         Thu Dec  7 11:14:04 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Dec  8 15:38:05 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Dec  8 15:48:07 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Dec  8 16:26:20 2023                 1
         Incremental         Fri Dec  8 16:55:20 2023                 1
-------------------------
No orphaned or incomplete backup sets found.
```

Comment: My script just has `duplicity --full-if-older-than 2W`, maybe your `backup` causes that behaviour?

Comment: If I omit that, it says "No valid action found. Will imply 'backup' because a path source was given and target is a url location." so I just specify it explicitly. The actual problem turned out to be a bug in the old version of duplicity that I was using, see answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be this known bug ["--full-if-older-than being ignored?"](https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/issues/764) which is supposedly fixed in [duplicity version 2.1.4](https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/blob/rel.2.1.4/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: That seems to have been it! I obviously should have tried updating duplicity. Thanks!